# Read every line in a file to ensure input id match

Tags: python, csv

I have this csv file that is uploaded and I want to check that the input id matches the one in this file. Here is what the output looks like. This file is part of a script that will run to check that the information was put in correctly. This is what the file looks like. I was thinking about creating a condition but I am having trouble narrowing down to the input id in the file. How can I do this?

```
Action  Object Type   Input ID
Add:    House Group   HG-Site-PIC
Add:    Service Team  HG-Site-PIC
Add:    Service       HG-Site-PIC
Modify      
Modify      
Modify      
Delete      
Delete      
Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

For csv reading/writing have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks will take a look and check back